# Installing xampp on Red Hat 64-bit

Tags: linux, 64-bit, redhat, lampp

When installing xampp on RHEL 5.6(Tikanga) 64-bit and start it up I get the following error:

```
lampp]# ./lampp start
XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility     library for your system.
```

Doing some reading up, the solutions only seem to be for ubuntu for installing the correct library. Red Hat solutions have been "Comment out the 64bit check in the lampp executable script" as follows:

```
================= 
# XAMPP is currently 32 bit only 
#case `uname -m` in 
# *_64) 
# if /opt/lampp/bin/php -v > /dev/null 2>&1 
# then 
# : 
# else 
# $de && echo "XAMPP gibt es zur Zeit nur als 32-Bit Applikation. Bitte verwende eine      32-Bit Kompatibilitaetsbibliothek fuer Dein System." 
# $de || echo "XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32    bit compatibility library for your system." 
# exit 
# fi 
# ;; 
#esac 
================
```

I have done this, started lampp again and now I get this:

```
lampp]# ./lampp start
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
Starting XAMPP for Linux ...
./lampp: line 133: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/nogroupcheck: No such file or directory
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 506: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/phpstatus: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting Apache...
./lampp: line 226: /opt/lampp/bin/apachectl: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Error 127! Couldn't start Apache!
./lampp: line 233: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/diagnose: No such file or directory
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
./lampp: line 253: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
cat: /opt/lampp/lib/VERSION: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 126: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/selinux: No such file or directory
./lampp: line 140: /opt/lampp/share/lampp/alladdons: No such file or directory
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

Turns out I probably do need some sort of library. Can anybody help me as to which?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install '**ia32-libs**' to allow 32bit binaries to run on 64bit architectures.